# How do I come back to the same activity after launching a new app without creating a new activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make payment using ATH Movil. So it needs to open the ATH Movil app and get the response from it either completed or cancel. After launching the ATH Movil app and getting the response, it is creating a new activity every time instead of coming back to the same activity which launched the app.

```
private static void execute(Context context, String json, long timeout) {
    PackageInfo athmInfo;
    int athmVersionCode = 0;
    String athmBundleId = COM_EVERTEC_ATHMOVIL_ANDROID + buildType;

    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(athmBundleId);
    try {
        athmInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(athmBundleId, 0);
        athmVersionCode = athmInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        logForDebug(e.getMessage());
    }
    if (intent == null || athmVersionCode <= ConstantUtil.ATH_MOVIL_REQUIRED_VERSION_CODE) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(ConstantUtil.ATH_MOVIL_MARKET_URL));
    }

    intent.putExtra((ConstantUtil.BUNDLE), context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(ConstantUtil.JSON_DATA_KEY, json);
    intent.putExtra(ConstantUtil.PAYMENT_DURATION_TIME_KEY, timeout);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

//        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
}

here is the manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="....ATHMSDK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also Activity1 implements PaymentResponseListener and onResume of Activity1 I am calling

PaymentResponse.validatePaymentResponse(getIntent(), Activity1.this); // this function is from their sdk and is read only.

Now when Activity1 launches the ATH Movil app and get the response. It creating again creating Activity1 instead of coming back to the existing one. Can somebody help me? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Activity` tag in `AndroidManifesto`:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

This assumes that you want to navigate back to the same `Task` that started the ATH Movil and the last item on the back stack was indeed `Activity1`. As long as these conditions hold true, then android OS will return you to the same instance of `Activity1`.

For more information on this, you can also refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack).